# dynamic setState and get state using es6 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Recently I learn about you can handle multiple input event using dynamic state.

If have state like this

```
this.state = {
   name_1: 'john',
   name_2: 'james'
}
```

I can get my state like this

```
[1,2].forEach(obj, i), => (
  console.log(this.state[`person_${i}`]);
))
```

But what about setState? What is the syntax like? I used this and it worked.

//says i is dynamic

```
this.setState({
  [`person_${i}`]: ''
})
```

Why above code work? it look like array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a new feature in ES6 Called `ComputedPropertyName`. You can initialize object with dynamic property names.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer).

In React ecosystem, it is commonly used to handle `input` changes:

```
handleChange(field, value) {
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
}

<input
  onChange={e => this.handleChange('firstName', e.target.value)}
/>
```